# Cannot use IIF in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot use IIF in the Where clause, I'm trying to filter by brandId if @BRAND_IDS exists, I will use this for filtering the data, if not just select data that the BRAND_ID is not equal to 0.

```sql
.....
 WHERE  pit.Item_Enable = 1
      AND p.Product_Enable = 1
      AND pit.Item_SellPrice > 0
      AND pit.Item_ListPrice > 0
    AND Product_Catalog in (select CATALOG_LV3_ID from @CatalogSearch)
 AND IIF(@BRAND_IDS IS NOT NULL, BRAND_ID IN (select b.BRAND_ID from @Brands b), BRAND_ID <> 0)
```

[image]

Comment: You *can* use an `IIF` in the `WHERE`; your mistake is trying to return a boolean result in the true and false values. Though you *shouldn't* be using an `IIF` in your `WHERE` like that; you should be using explicit Boolean clauses with `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you can simulate True by using case when something then 1 else 0 end = 1 for example, so your where could be rewritten using a couple of nested case whens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IIF()` needs to return a value, not an expression and so you cannot use it in the way you're trying to.

But all is not lost! I think this is equivalent to what you're trying to do with the `IIF()`:

```sql
(
    (@BRAND_IDS IS NOT NULL AND BRAND_ID in (select b.BRAND_ID from @Brands b))
    OR (@BRAND_IDS IS NULL AND BRAND_ID <> 0)
)
```